# Stripping variable suffix off Wordpress title

Tags: php, wordpress, preg-replace, echo, str-replace

I'm trying to strip a variable suffix off my Wordpress titles, basically a bunch of hastags from posts imported from Instagram that are preceeded by an hyphen and I've come up with something like this:

```
<?php
$titleoutput = get_the_title($ID);
$titleoutputstrip = preg_replace("/\-/", "", $titleoutput); 
echo $titleoutputstrip;
?>
```

But it doesn't seem to be working.

Can anyone help me out?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why use a regex for something so simple? `$out = str_replace('-', '', $in)` would be FAR more efficient than hauling out regex artillery.

Comment: `But it doesn't seem to be working.` How doesn't it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally nailed it with:

```
<?php
$titleoutput = get_the_title($ID);
$titleoutputstrip = preg_replace('/\ #[^.]+$/','',$titleoutput);
echo $titleoutputstrip;
?>
```

The hyphen was giving me problems because it's actually a dash "–" or something like that so I just set it to look for the first hashtag and erase the contents to the end.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$titleoutput = get_the_title($ID);
$titleoutputstrip = ltrim($titleoutput , '-'); // ltrim for begining  rtrim for end
echo $titleoutputstrip;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks but this only removes the dash if it's the last character on the sentence. The dash actually appears in the middle and I want to erase it and all the variable text after it.

Comment: Complete example:

    <?php
    $titleoutput = 'Text to Keep - Text I want to remove which is not always the same';
    $titleoutputstrip = rtrim($titleoutput,'-'); // ltrim for begining  rtrim for end
   echo $titleoutputstrip;
    ?>

Doesn't work, that '-' value needs some variable.